# how to add brush in nvd3 like d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am creating graph in nvd3 [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/kxmzo0af/1/)

I am done with graph and its working nicely but now I want to add **brush** in it like **d3** see this example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367. but i searched every where, i found one solution i.e [crossfilter](http://square.github.io/crossfilter/) but is it possible to use brush like d3 and nvd3 has any brush function ? please help me.

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
    var chart = nv.models.multiBarChart();

    chart.xAxis
        .tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));

    chart.yAxis
        .tickFormat(d3.format(',.1f'));

    chart.multibar.stacked(true); // default to stacked
    chart.showControls(true); // don't show controls

    d3.select('#chart svg')
        .datum(test_data)
      .transition().duration(500).call(chart);

    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

    return chart;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wonder how can you add brush using crossfilter?

Any way here is the solution

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
    var chart = nv.models.multiBarChart();

    chart.xAxis
        .tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));

    chart.yAxis
        .tickFormat(d3.format(',.1f'));

    chart.multibar.stacked(true); // default to stacked
    chart.showControls(true); // don't show controls

    d3.select('#chart svg')
        .datum(test_data)
      .transition().duration(500).call(chart);




    var brushC  = d3.select('#chart svg g');

    brushC.empty() ? brushC.append('g'): brushC.select('g')
    .attr("class", "brush")
        .call(d3.svg.brush()        
            .x(chart.xAxis.scale())
            .on('brushend', onBrush)
            .extent([0,0])  

        )
        .selectAll('rect')
        .attr('height',320 )//change according to you chart height
         //i have hard coded it since it was a 'quick and dirty' fix
        //you may try to get it from chart, if you can please update me.
        ;
    }


 nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
        return chart;
    });
```

onBrush Function

```
function onBrush() {
    brushExtent = d3.event.target.extent();
    console.log(brushExtent);
}
```

add CSS

```
rect.extent{
    color:grey;
    opacity:0.4;
}
```